# How to get access token / Authentication token of facebook user with 'token' response_type?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

In my c# application I am trying to get accesstoken/authentication token for user using facebook c# sdk.
If I use response_type = 'code' then I am getting data in my callback function but when I use  response_type = 'token' then data is coming as null.
Bellow is my code when i use response_type = 'code'

```
  private Uri RedirectUri
    {
        get
        {
            var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
            uriBuilder.Query = null;
            uriBuilder.Fragment = null;
            uriBuilder.Path = Url.Action("FacebookCallback");
            return uriBuilder.Uri;
        }
    }
  public ActionResult FacebookLogin()
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        var loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(new
        {
            client_id = "146137372750966",
            client_secret = "",
            redirect_uri = RedirectUri.AbsoluteUri,
            response_type = "code",
            scope = "public_profile,email",
            state = "gsdfgjpfosd34956834"
        });

        return Redirect(loginUrl.AbsoluteUri);

    }

    public ActionResult FacebookCallback(string code)
    {
    }
```

Bellow is code when i use response_type = 'token'

```
private Uri RedirectUri
    {
        get
        {
            var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
            uriBuilder.Query = null;
            uriBuilder.Fragment = null;
            uriBuilder.Path = Url.Action("FacebookCallback");
            return uriBuilder.Uri;
        }
    }

 public ActionResult FacebookLogin()
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        var loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(new
        {
            client_id = "146137372750966",
            client_secret = "",
            redirect_uri = RedirectUri.AbsoluteUri,
            response_type = "token",
            scope = "public_profile,email",
            state = "gsdfgjpfosd34956834"
        });

        return Redirect(loginUrl.AbsoluteUri);

    }

    public ActionResult FacebookCallback(string code)
    {
    }
```

I am not able to identify the mistake I am doing when passing response_type = "token",

Url which is returning is something like this.

```
http://localhost:32432/FacebookCallback?#state=gsdfgjpfosd34956834&access_token=lfahfegldskgjsdgdslkkghlsgfsgmndf;lhjd&expires_in=3927
```

How do I read this in my callback function ?

Comment: Why do you want to use that response type in the first place? This is mainly intended for purely client-side apps, that don’t have a server-side component.

Comment: Now I understood, I can not use response_type = "token" on server side.

Comment: No, the hash part of a URL does not get send to the server, it is a merely client-side construct.

Comment: Then how can i get access token on server side with this ?

Comment: By catching it on the client side, and then sending it to the server using an additional HTTP request ... Or you handle this on the server to begin with, by using response_type=code.

Comment: Can you please share some example for same ?